# Выдает ошибку ConnectionError

Tags: python, api

api.py

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.unsplash/search/collections?page=1&per_page=30&client_id=GJwOGWLHUtupIb6PRH7cjtmj6MoDyyzwyVp2TyaPYKc")

print(r.text)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unapi.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://api.unsplash/search/collections?page=1&per_page=30&client_id=GJwOGWLHUtupIb6PRH7cjtmj6MoDyyzwyVp2TyaPYKc")
  File "E:\Python\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.unsplash', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search/collections?page=1&per_page=30&client_id=GJwOGWLHUtupIb6PRH7cjtmj6MoDyyzwyVp2TyaPYKc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x029E0110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
(env)
```

Когда с помощью vpn по https://api.unsplash/search/collections?page=1&per_page=30&client_id=GJwOGWLHUtupIb6PRH7cjtmj6MoDyyzwyVp2TyaPYKc этой ссылке захожу все показывает, а когда захожу без vpn, пишет "Не удается получить доступ к сайту". Помогите пожалуйста!

Пробовал через прокси

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': 'http://37.187.16.11:80'}

r = requests.get("https://api.unsplash.com/search/collections?page=1&query=snow&client_id=GJwOGWLHUtupIb6PRH7cjtmj6MoDyyzwyVp2TyaPYKc", proxies=proxies)

print(r.text)
```

Ссылка работает только через VPN.

Comment: Ошибка "getaddrinfo failed" означает, что не удалось найти такое доменное имя. Это что за TLD такой unsplash? Подозреваю, должно быть api.unsplash.com

Comment: Я попробовал добавить .com, но к сожалению вылезает та же ошибка (

Comment: Нет, если добавить .com, то вылазит совсем другая ошибка: {"errors":["query is missing"]}

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня к сожалению та же ошибка

Comment: @XimizIvanov У меня и в браузере и через питон показывает то, что я написал

Comment: прекрасно работает с вашим `proxies`. в какой вы стране?

Comment: Я нахожусь в Казахстане

Comment: 185.137.232.95:80 попробуйте

Comment: Не работает, та же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы смотрели [документацию](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-collections)?

Пример из документации: `https://api.unsplash.com/search/collections?page=1&query=office`

Соответственно:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/collections?page=1&query=snow&client_id=<...>')

print(r.content)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я попробовал то что вы написали, но опять же выскакивает ошибка: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: ссылка у вас в браузере открывается? client_id не забыли подставить свой?

Comment: Client_id поставил. Вот только открывается ссылка только через vpn

Comment: а в какой Вы стране, что у вас unsplash заблокирован.. в таком случае используйте прокси для requests `proxies=...`

Comment: Я кстати proxies использовал, тоже не вышло

Comment: Правда я пробовал через JS, там все получилось

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте в него все ваши попытки, что использовали для proxies, через какой (страна) впн открывается ссылка...